# Yii2 updateAll Как задать 2 параметра поиска

Tags: yii2

Подскажите как задать 2 параметра поиска для updateAll, пример:

```
updateAll(
    ['name' => 'Вася', 'last_name' => 'Петров'],
    ['id' => 1, 'city' => 'Moskow']
);
```

так все работает, но как задать что city != Moskow

Comment: @param string|array $condition the conditions that will be put in the WHERE part of the UPDATE SQL. Please refer to [[Query::where()]] on how to specify this parameter. Если влом разбираться, то можно просто строкой вписать на скл, это даже понагляднее извратов под != самого фреймворка.

Comment: Что это? Можно объяснить?

Comment: вы можете написать дословно "id = 1 and city != Moskow" строкой вместо массива

Comment: Пишу так: ['id=1 and city<>Moskow'] - не работает

Comment: а вы без [] пишите

Answer (score 3):

Если кому то понадобится, нашел решение!

```
updateAll(
     ['name' => 'Вася', 'last_name' => 'Петров'],
     ['AND', ['=', 'id', 1],['<>', 'city', 'Moskow']
 );
```